# Android, intent error "not defined"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, switch-statement

My Eclipse gives an error message with intents in switch: `The constructor Intent (new Adapter.View.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class <UlohaShowerActivity>) is undefined`

All project intents are OK, but this can get a reason. I don't know what is wrong with this statement. I am using exactly these intents from other activities and it works great, activities are in manifest and ... only in this switch and OnItemClick is there the error.

Here's my code for the activity,

```
public class HladajListActivity extends Activity 
{
private DatabaseOp mDbHelper;
public static final String HOW = "how";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String DATE = "date";
public static final String TYP = "typ";

int how;
String name;
String date;
int typ;

String username;
String nazov;
String datum;

ListView listview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hladaj);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    how = Integer.parseInt(i.getStringExtra(HOW));
    name = i.getStringExtra(NAME);
    date = i.getStringExtra(DATE);
    typ = Integer.parseInt(i.getStringExtra(TYP));

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHladaj);

    mDbHelper = new DatabaseOp(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    showUserSettings(); 
    Cursor hladajCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllFind(username, name, date, how, typ);

    final HladajCursorAdapter adapter = new HladajCursorAdapter(this, hladajCursor);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (listview.getCount()==0)
        setContentView(R.layout.hladaj_empty);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int stlpec, long arg3) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Cursor cur = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(stlpec);

            String typ = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("typ"));
            String odosli = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));

            switch (Integer.parseInt(typ)) 
            {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,UlohaShowerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(UlohaShowerActivity.ODOSLI, odosli);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PredmetShowerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PredmetShowerActivity.ODOSLI, odosli);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PoznamkaShowerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PoznamkaShowerActivity.ODOSLI, odosli);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
    mDbHelper.close();
}


private void showUserSettings() 
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    username = sharedPrefs.getString("prefUsername", "NULL");
}

}
```

Comment: try this way    `Intent intent = new Intent(HladajListActivity .this,UlohaShowerActivity.class);` also change for all other cases

Comment: have you add that activity in manifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,UlohaShowerActivity.class);
```

To

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HladajListActivity.this,UlohaShowerActivity.class);
```

and also change for all other cases. You have to pass `Activity Context` as first Argument of `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
new Intent(this
```

with

```
new Intent(HladajListActivity.this
```

`this` inside the `OnItemClickListener` refers to the `OnItemClickListener` instance and not the outer activity instance. You need to explicitly refer to the activity which is a `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,UlohaShowerActivity.class);
```

TO

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(HladajListActivity.this,UlohaShowerActivity.class);
```

And

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,PoznamkaShowerActivity.class);
```

TO

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HladajListActivity.this,PoznamkaShowerActivity.class);
```

Your [this]  is just the instance of `OnItemClickListener` not of `Activity`.